# css on table borders

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and have a small problem.I am creating a news feed page and want to separate each feed from the other.see the image i have attached to see what i exactly want.[image]

heres what i have tried so far...

```
<html>
 <style type = text/css>
td.border
{
border-right-style: hidden;
border-left-style: hidden;
border-top-style: hidden;
border-bottom-color: #999;
}
</style>
<table width="90%" align="center" cellpadding="4"   bgcolor="#A6D2FF">
    <tr>
      <td width="7%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a    href="http://www.project360.in/emp_profile.php?id=uid">Name</a><br />
      </td>
      <td width="93%" class = "border" bgcolor="#D9ECFF"> <span style="font-size:10px;  font-weight:bold; color:#A6A6A6;">Date</span><br />
      ufeed</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question code to include only the relevant HTML and CSS. This is unrelated to PHP.

Comment: First of all, don't use a table for this. This is a typical unordered list (`ul`) - or an ordered list (`ol`), if you want.

Comment: @bazmegakapa : thats a good suggestion but what if i do use it?because the above code is not working...is there any syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try use border-top/left/right/bottom instead of *-style and *-color:

```
td.border
{
border-right: none;
border-left: none;
border-top: none;
border-bottom: 1px #999 solid;
}
```

And as mentioned above - you shouldn't use table for things like that.

Comment: Or instead of the first 3 rules, simply `border: none;`. `border-bottom` will override it for the bottom border.